# Como agregar la sesion de usuario en un formulario en Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

Tengo un formulario que recoje informacion acerca de una recarga de saldo. Este formulario tiene un campo llamado usuario, que debe guardar el nombre o id del usuario que inicio sesion.
Para entender mejor les muestro el archivo models.py:

```
class Recarga(models.Model):
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    monto = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    medio_pago = models.CharField(max_length=60, choices=lista_medios_pago)
    saldo = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    estatus = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%i' % self.id
```

En el archivo form.py esta definido de esta manera:

```
class RecargasForm(ModelForm):

    monto = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        "class": "form-control",
        "type": "number",
        "max":"999",
        "required": "True",
        "autocomplete": "Off",
        "placeholder": "Monto a recargar"
    }), label="Monto Recarga")

    class Meta:
        model = Recarga
        fields = [
            'monto',
            'medio_pago',
            'saldo',
            'estatus',
            'usuario'
        ]
        labels = {
            'medio_pago': 'Medio de Pago',
        }
        widgets = {
            'medio_pago': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control selectpicker'}),
            'saldo': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }
```

Y el archivo html donde se muestra el formulario contiene:

```
{% block content %}
{% include "nav.html" %}

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4 mx-auto">
            <h2 class="text-center">Agregar Recarga</h2>
                
                {{ form.as_p }}

            <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Agregar</button>
            <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017–2022</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Cuando se ejecuta la aplicacion, el formulario muestra en el campo usuarios, todos los usuarios que se han registrado en el sistema, y solo deberia mostrar al usuario activo o logueado en ese momento.

[vista del formulario de recarga](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVpKL.png)

¿Como hago para que en vez de una lista de todos los usuarios registrados, solo me muestre el usuario activo o logueado en el sistema?

Trate de crear el formulario de manera independiente, es decir, llamando a cada uno de los campos, pero se presenta el inconveniente que el campo "metodos de pago" es una lista que esta en el archivo model.py

Answer (score 1):

Para comenzar, puedes hacer uso de esta librería para obtener el usuario actual desde el form

https://pypi.org/project/django-crum/

Una vez que lo tienes, están 2 opciones:

Mostrar el campo de usuario como un select donde la única opción del select sea el usuario actual

```
#importar librería 
from crum import get_current_user
class RecargasForm(ModelForm):
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           super().__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
           current = get_current_user()
           self.fields['usuario'].queryset= User.objects..get(pk=current.pk)
```

O la otra opción es quitar al usuario del formulario y sobrescribir el método save para que tome al usuario actual

```
def save(self, commit=False, *args,**kwargs):
    instance = super().save(commit=False, *args, **kwargs)
    instance.usuario =get_current_user()
    instance.save()
    return instance
```